# How to change parameters of saved model without training docs in Gensim Doc2Vec?

Tags: parameters, model, gensim, doc2vec

I preprocess my docs, trained my model, and saved it by following the guidelines given here: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html

After a period of time, I want to re-train my model with different parameters. However, I don't want to preprocess docs and create "train corpus" again because it takes nearly 3 days. Is there a solution to easily load saved model, change parameters and train the model with these new parameters for the following codes:

```
model = Doc2Vec.load(myPath/myModel.doc2vec)
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=300, min_count=2, epochs=40, dm=1, window=8)
model.build_vocab(train_corpus)
model.train(train_corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
```

Best.

Comment: Which parameters do you want to change? Are you using the same training corpus each time?

Comment: Yes, the training corpus will remain the same. I will adjust vector_size, epochs, dm and window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that this section of your current code does nothing with the loaded model, because it's immediately replaced by the *new* model created by the 2nd line's instantiation of a model from scratch:

```py
model = Doc2Vec.load(myPath/myModel.doc2vec)
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=300, min_count=2, epochs=40, dm=1, window=8)
```

Second, in general, you can `.save()` a model **after** the `.build_vocab()` step, to then re-load that model for multiple later training sessions. And, a bunch of the model's parameters can be direcly changed, by simply assigning them new values (like `d2v_model.window = 10`) before that training, to affect it. For example:

```py
d2v_model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=300, min_count=2, epochs=40, dm=1, window=8)
d2v_model.build_vocab(training_texts)
d2v_model.save(base_model_path)
```

Then, later:

```py
d2v_model_w10 = Doc2Vec.load(base_model_path)
d2v_model_w10.window = 10
d2v_model_w10.train(training_texts, total_examples=d2v_model_w10.corpus_count, epochs=d2v_model_w10.epochs)
```

Some of the model parameters for which this modification *after* `.build_vocab()` modification should work well include:

- `window`
- `sg` (in `Word2Vec`) or `dm`/`dbow_words` (in `Doc2Vec`)
- `negative` (if changing between positive values)
- `workers`
- `alpha`, `min_alpha`

*However*, parameters which chiefly affect the `.build_vocab()` step, which includes discovering the working vocabulary & allocating the starting vectors, or pre-calculating vocabulary-based values, **won't** change model behavior if modified after `.build_vocab()` was run. Some of these parameters include:

- `vector_size` (because `.build_vocab()`'s last step allocates vectors)
- `min_count`, `max_final_vocab`, `trim_rule`
- `hs` (or changing `negative` between zero & positive numbers)
- `sample`, `ns_exponent` (threshold tables calculated in `.build_vocab`)

(At a more-expert level, it *is* possible to save a model after the costly 1st vocabulary-scan, but before the final-steps. That would allow a load-then-change for most of these - but you should look at the [source for `Doc2Vec.build_vocab()`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f8964f4411964b0175589784ffa4a9b8f540e49c/gensim/models/doc2vec.py#L827) for hints. You'd have to never call `.build_vocab()`, but call the scan steps yourself, then `.save()`. Then after `.load()` & changing parameters, call the `.prepare_vocab()` & `.prepare_weights()` steps.)

Finally, & separately from your main question, if your corpus is large enough for the training step to take 3 days, some things to consider:

- `epochs=40` may be excessive - a lot of published work uses just 10-20 epochs, and more epochs are more often needed on smaller training sets.
- with a large corpus, using a larger `min_count` often shrinks model size & training time, with either no hit to quality, or even improving quality (by eliminating rare words which never become more than noise)
- with a large corpus, more aggressive (smaller) values of `sample` can save a lot of time, especially with true natural language text in with Zipfian word frequencies. (Highly-frequent words don't need so mcuh redundant training, so more-aggressively skipping them both saves time & improves the relative-attention-given-to, and quality of, rarer words.)

Comment: Thanks @gojomo, very helpful and detailed explanations. Extra thanks for the last hints, I will apply them. Regarding the main concept, since I need to modify window size, it will be better for me to preprocess corpus because I am not an expert to call .build_vocab() parts.